# Threejs, making glass shatter effect

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an idea to create, but since my knowledge about Three.js and 3D programming in general is limited, I am stuck...
Idea: User is doing some things. At some point - whole front screen crashes, and reveals something different behind.
At the beginning, my idea was - make screenshot, of what is happening right now, put that image in front of everything (still, having difficulties making that plane to take 100% size - idea - when it shows, user cannot tell the difference, between old 3d renderings, and new 2d picture), and then - shatter it. So - by looking around the Web for different examples, I made some... thing - Created screenshot, made plane and applied screenshot as a texture to it. To create shattering effect, I used TessellateModifier to divide that plane, and ExplodeModifier to create each face as separated face.
Here will be the code I made so far.

```
function drawSS()
{
    var img = new Image;
    img.onload = function() { // When screenshot is ready
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        // CANVAS DRAWINGS
        // Draws screenshot
        // END
        var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas);
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
        var multiMaterial = [
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: texture, side: THREE.FrontSide}), // canvas drawings
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, wireframe: true, transparent: true}) // for displaying wireframe
            ]; 

        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(canvas.width, canvas.height); // create plane

        for (var i = 0, len = geometry.faces.length; i < len; i++) { // Snippet from some stackoverflow post, that works.
            var face = geometry.faces[i].clone();
            face.materialIndex = 1;
            geometry.faces.push(face);
            geometry.faceVertexUvs[0].push(geometry.faceVertexUvs[0][i].slice(0));
        }

        geometry.dynamic = true;

        THREE.GeometryUtils.center( geometry ); // ?

        var tessellateModifier = new THREE.TessellateModifier( 10 );

        for ( var i = 0; i < 5; i ++ )
            tessellateModifier.modify( geometry );

        new THREE.ExplodeModifier().modify( geometry );

        geometry.vertices[0].x -=300;
        geometry.vertices[1].x -=300;
        geometry.vertices[2].x -=300;

        var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(multiMaterial) );
        scene.add( mesh );
    };
        // THEN, set the src
    img.src = THREEx.Screenshot.toDataURL(renderer);
}
```

For now - I moved 1 face, by changing coordinates of 3 vertices. I'm asking - if this approach is the way to go? Result looks like this. (white lines - wireframe, black lines - (drawings in canvas) my desired wireframes - problem for later). Note - by moving this way - texture goes along, I don't know, if I make new triangles using these vertices, how would I set texture.
[image]